# how to get cell number as a result of a function

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice

i need to get № of a cell that contains the result of MAX(J4:J24) and write a word from the same row instead of the actual max number

the word can be written i guess via =INDIRECT("A"&formula here)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the row number of the cell with the max value like this:

```
=match(max(j4:j24),J:J,0)
```

If the text you want to display is in column A, you can use that row number to get the cell in column A in that row.

```
=index(A:A,match(max(j4:j24),J:J,0))
```

If more than one number in the range are equal to the maximum, then only the first match will be returned.